# IR3315 input control grounding?

Tags: switches

I'm considering using a [IR3315](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/auir3315.pdf) as a replacement for a PTC fuse. I dont need current sensing nor logic control of it. I just want it to shut down if a given current is reached, and need it to come back if I unplug power and plug back in.

I read the datasheet and [this](http://www.irf.com/technical-info/appnotes/an-1118.pdf) app note but it wasn't clear to me if I can just ground the IN pin to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes you can just ground the IN pin. As the last paragraph states [image]

As previously mentioned in the datasheet, Ifb is proportional to the power mosfet current. Thus you can assume it to be a current source. As the quote says, shutdown is the difference between the two voltages, so you can say whatever voltage you set your input control to is essentially a local ground to the current sense side of things. As the current increases, Vifb (=Ifb * Rifb + Vin)will increase until Vifb-Vin>4.7V and the entire thing turns off.

By this you can set Vinput_control to whatever voltage you want, specifically the one that will allow Vcc-Vin > 6 V (or whatever Vih actually is for your device). If 6 V is your desired turn on voltage than grounding them would work.

Finally, I hope that this is a logical exercise, or that you eventually want to use the current sense side of things, because this chip is more expensive than a PTC fuse, requires more components, and clearly is more complicated :)

Comment: The preference for this IC instead of PTC is because of the speed and versatility. I can buy just one of these devices and set the current. While with PTCs I have to stock different values. Current sense is a plus also for later projects.

Comment: cool. just wanted to make sure that aspect had been covered